# Execute a method according to device's time

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a `timePicker`

```
    String mName = input.getText().toString();
    if (input.getParent() != null)
        ((ViewGroup) input.getParent()).removeView(input);
    if (layout.getParent() != null)
        ((ViewGroup) layout.getParent()).removeView(layout);
    mAlertDialog.dismiss();

    Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
    mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(Chat.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Make sure you have internet access at this time selected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }, hour, minute, true);// Yes 24 hour time
    mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
    mTimePicker.show();
```

I want a method to execute at the time picked by the user. How can i achieve this. Say i want to change a particular data in firebase at the given time how can i do that? Please help me out

Comment: You can use WorkManager for this, just schedule your task to time, picked in time picker

Comment: i didnt quite understand the docs... Could u answer for setting a value to something.. example mDatabase.setValue("TOSOMETHING"); @AntonShkurenko

Comment: Write a function in Cloud Function and call it at a particular tine using a cron job.

Comment: can i get the code @AlexMamo

Comment: [This](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html) explains how to setup periodic cron jobs with firebase. Store the time and name of the function to be executed in the database and check periodically if some function needs to be executed.